# Time Comparison In Reversing a Number

Tags: java

In program of java for reversing a number, I did in two ways.

First mathematically:

Find the greatest power of 10 smaller than or equal to number.

Multiply it with the rightmost digit.

divide the number by 10.

repeat until number is 0.

Second using Inbuilt method reverse of StringBuffer and converting back to integer.

To my surprise, the second way, although pretty short came out to be slower by large amount. I thought that using inbuilt function would be faster .But results said otherwise, Is there a reason for this observation.The results were same for small numbers(3 digit) and large numbers(9 digit).

Here is my java code:

```
class RevNum
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 {  
     int n=987,n2=n;     
     long ft,st;     
     int s=0,r=0,p;     
     st=System.nanoTime();
     while(n!=0)
     {
         p=(int)Math.pow(10,power(n));         
         r+= n%10*p;
         n=n/10;
     } 
     ft=System.nanoTime()-st;
     System.out.println("the time taken is "+ft+" and reversed number is "+r);     
     st=System.nanoTime();
     StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(n2));     
     n2= Integer.parseInt(new String(str.reverse()));
     ft=System.nanoTime()-st;
     System.out.println("the time taken is "+ft+" and reversed number is "+n2);                
 }
 private static int power(int n)
 {
     int s=0;
     while(n/10!=0)
      {
          ++s;
          n=n/10;
      }
     return s;     
 }
}
```

Comment: This `Integer.toString(n2)` probably already takes more time than your loop...

Comment: Of course converting a number to a string, reversing the string and parsing it back into a number will be slower than just a bunch of arithmetic operations, at least for reasonably sized numbers.

Comment: what about small numbers.

Comment: Sorry, with reasonably sized numbers I meant numbers with not too many digits and I'm not sure when it _might_ start to become slower (depending on a good implementation for int->string and string->int).

Comment: Btw, your approach might be even faster if instead of calling `Math.pow(10, power(n))` you'd just multiply `s` by 10 in the `power()` method and skip `Math.pow()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reverse using your mathematical solution, you only iterate over the numbers once.  When you convert it to a StringBuffer, reverse it, and then back to an Integer, you are iterating over the numbers multiple times.  Your mathematical method additionally does not have heavy computations, just simple arithmetic.

This is particularly why sometimes building your own methods is more efficient than using built-in functions if you know how to do it and you know how things are optimized.  Many built-in functions are designed to be incredibly flexible, but the trade-off is they also take more time or memory or both.